# How to fix these errors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, tikz-styles

Could anyone help fixing the error and shift the table's legend up a bit?  
Can you make the table legend with TikZ instead of `\legend`?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}b{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}}
\legend{Weighted, complete graph $K_H$}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
state/.append style={minimum size=5mm}]
%\begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
    \node [state] (0) at (-2, 3) [label=left:E] {};
    \node [state] (1) at ( 2, 3) [label=right:B]{};
    \node [state] (2) at (-1.25, 0.75)[label=left:D] {};
    \node [state] (3) at ( 1.25, 0.75) [label=right:C]{};
    \node [state] (4) at ( 0, 4.5) [label=above: A]{};
%\end{pgfonlayer}
%\begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
    \draw  (0) to (4);
    \draw (4) to (1);
    \draw (1) to (3);
    \draw (0) to (2);
    \draw (3) to (2);
    \draw (2) to (4);
    \draw (4) to (3);
    \draw (0) to (1);
    \draw (0) to (3);
    \draw (2) to (1);
%\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

    &
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\legend{\textbf{THIS IS TABLE LEGEND}}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccccc}
 & A  & B & C & D & E  \\
\hline
A & --  & 4 & 7 & 6 & 12 \\
B & 4  & -- & 3 & 5 & 8  \\
C & 7  & 3 & -- & 2 & 5  \\
D & 6  & 5 & 2 & -- & 9  \\
E & 12 & 8 & 5 & 9 & --
\end{tabular}

\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `standalone` is not intended to contain floats. If you persist to contain it, than you need to add option `varwidth`: `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}`. Where you define `\legend˛command? Does it should be caption?

Comment: @Zarko I'm going to export it as PDF and then insert to document as figure so I don't want to add caption. I placed the legend command right at the begining of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}}
\textbf{Weighted, complete graph $K_H$}
    &   \textbf{THIS IS TABLE LEGEND}   \\    
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
scale=0.8,   
state/.style = {circle, draw, minimum width=5mm, inner sep=0pt}
                    ]
    \node [state] (e) at (-2, 3) [label=left:E] {};
    \node [state] (b) at ( 2, 3) [label=right:B]{};
    \node [state] (d) at (-1.25, 0.75)[label=left:D] {};
    \node [state] (c) at ( 1.25, 0.75) [label=right:C]{};
    \node [state] (a) at ( 0, 4.5) [label=above: A]{};
\draw   (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e) -- (a) 
        (a) -- (c) -- (e) -- (b) -- (d) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
    &   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc}
            & A & B & C & D & E  \\
            \hline
          A & --  & 4 & 7 & 6 & 12 \\
          B & 4  & -- & 3 & 5 & 8  \\
          C & 7  & 3 & -- & 2 & 5  \\
          D & 6  & 5 & 2 & -- & 9  \\
          E & 12 & 8 & 5 & 9 & --
       \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

- If you only need `<file name>.pfd` file, which you will include with `\includegraphics{file.name>}  in your main document, than is advisable to simplified above MWE to:

```
% file name
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\textbf{Weighted, complete graph $K_H$}
    &   \textbf{This is table legend}   \\
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
scale=0.8,
state/.style = {circle, draw, minimum width=5mm, inner sep=0pt}
                    ]
    \node [state] (e) at (-2, 3) [label=left:E] {};
    \node [state] (b) at ( 2, 3) [label=right:B]{};
    \node [state] (d) at (-1.25, 0.75)[label=left:D] {};
    \node [state] (c) at ( 1.25, 0.75) [label=right:C]{};
    \node [state] (a) at ( 0, 4.5) [label=above: A]{};
\draw   (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e) -- (a)
        (a) -- (c) -- (e) -- (b) -- (d) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
    &   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc}
         & A  & B & C & D & E  \\
        \hline
        A & --  & 4 & 7 & 6 & 12 \\
        B & 4  & -- & 3 & 5 & 8  \\
        C & 7  & 3 & -- & 2 & 5  \\
        D & 6  & 5 & 2 & -- & 9  \\
        E & 12 & 8 & 5 & 9 & --
        \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

- In both cases you need to care, that width of images will not be bigger than `\textwidth` in the main document.

Comment: May I set the smaller borders? I want to export it as PDF so I don't want it to have large margin.

Comment: @hana, you can set any border as you wish. However, now is not clear how you will use this figure, i.e. how it will be insert to your document where will be inserted caption.

Comment: I tried `\documentclass[border={1cm}]{standalone}` but it doesn't work. The table and figure above is exported as one single PDF file and then I'll use `\includegraphics` to insert that to my document.

Comment: `\caption*{\textbf{This is table legend}}` would be good too but I don't know how to make it center aligned.

Comment: @hana, hm, if I understand you, than from my MWE you should remove option `varwidth` and float `figure˛environment. Any `standalone` border with add disturbing space around of figure. You also may consider to insert figure code directly in your document.

Comment: @hana, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619556/, it may help you to solve your problem. However, if you have new problem, ask new question.

Comment: I decided to export to PDF instead of inserting code as it's simpler to do that way. Removing `varwidth` causes an error but I think the current form is good enough.

Comment: @hana, as @Zarko said, to prepare a clean PDF for including later you should remove the `figure` environment --- this is doing nothing here. Don't get confused by the name: the `figure` environment means "add some material that will float around and will be labeled as a figure" --- you will have the figure environment in the document that *includes * your PDF, not here!

Comment: Thank  you. I tried removing that but somehow I got some weird errors so I gave up but it works now.

Comment: `In both cases you need to care, that width of images will not be bigger than \textwidth in the main document.` Can I just do this ` \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]` in my document instead of worrying about that image size?

Comment: @hana, no. Standalone doesn't know the size of  `\textwidth` in your main document.

Comment: If possible, could you give an example on how to set the size? for example I want to set image size to fit `textwidth = 3cm`, assuming that I export that to file.pdf to include to my document?

Comment: @hana, please ask new question. Where cleare describe what you after. You should be aware, that `standalone` is designed so, that image canvas is adopted to size of images + declared borders. See package documentation for details.